# JPA + Hibernate + MySQL: How to propagate a schema into the connection?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have several independent components in my application. Each has its own data model within a DB schema:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sample")  // the table name is not unique among components (schemas)
public class SampleEntity1 { ... }
```

Analogically for `SampleEntity2`.

Each component brings its own `persistence-unitX.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence https://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="unit1" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <mapping-file>META-INF/orm-unit1.xml</mapping-file>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
        </properties>
        <class>com.example.model1.SampleEntity1</class>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And the mapping file `orm-unitX.xml` sets the schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity-mappings version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm">
    <persistence-unit-metadata>
        <persistence-unit-defaults>
            <schema>schema1</schema>
        </persistence-unit-defaults>
    </persistence-unit-metadata>
</entity-mappings>
```

Analogically for the other components.

To make it work I would expect a connection string without the database part, e.g.: `jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306`.

Unfortunatelly, such a setting throws an exception:

> java.sql.SQLException: No database selected

Setting a database (schema) into the connection string (e.g.: `jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/myschema`) throws no exception, but doesn't work as wanted - only one schema is used and entities with the same table name are merged into a single database table.

No luck with setting the property `hibernate.default_schema`, too.

Is there a way how to propagate JPA schema setting into the database connection with Hibernate and MySQL?

---

I'm using Spring Data (Spring Boot Data-Jpa starter 2.1.5.RELEASE) and MySQL 8 
 - shouldn't have any impact.

The whole scenario works when using EclipseLink instead of Hibernate, so the problem seems to be in Hibernate.

[Here](https://github.com/ttulka/spring-boot-samples/tree/master/hibernate-multi-schema-model-mysql) is a sample project.

Comment: we dont do that here  :P --> https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-rest-api-tutorial-with-mysql-jpa-hibernate/

Comment: @emotionlessbananas ???

Comment: No because for MySQL this is not a schema but a database.
This means it's a mandatory part in the database connection. Where do you create the datasource?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I understand, but for mysql a [schema is a synonym of database](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/glossary.html#glos_schema). A connection string without a database provides a connection to the server, then it should be possible to select a database to work with (`use mydb`). The whole scenario works when using EclipseLink instead of Hibernate, so the problem must be in Hibernate.

Comment: Oh I understand. Sorry. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use catalog instead of schema in the orm.xml for Hibernate and MySQL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity-mappings version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm">
    <persistence-unit-metadata>
        <persistence-unit-defaults>
            <catalog>schema1</catalog>
        </persistence-unit-defaults>
    </persistence-unit-metadata>
</entity-mappings>
```

From the docs: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html

> The schema attribute of the @Table annotation works only if the
>   underlying database supports schemas (e.g. PostgreSQL).
>
> Therefore, if you’re using MySQL or MariaDB, which do not support
>   schemas natively (schemas being just an alias for catalog), you need
>   to use the catalog attribute, and not the schema one.

Comment: It actually works, thank you very much! Is there any documentation explaining this?